# Kriyah at time of death when it occurs on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, death

When somone is there at Yitzias Neshomah (time of death) there is a requirement to rip Kriyah what happens if this situation occurs on Shabbos? Do you rip Kriyah or do the laws of Shabbos prevent you from doing so?

Comment: A chassidic master once told me that ripping keriyah on one's soul (i.e., feeling the pain of part of Klal Yisrael being destroyed) is always more important than ripping keriyah on one's garment. It is also more meaningful, because doing it on one's garment is not necessarily a mind-engaging activity. Therefore, even you maintain the position that on saturdays it is permitted to tear keriyah on a garment, the more important thing is the keriyah on your soul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, definitely not - both on Shabbos and Yom Tov.

The [Mishna](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%92) and [Gemara](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%A7%D7%94_%D7%91) in Shabbos are discussing whether the one did it is exempt from bringing a Korbon (after the fact). The Gemara ends up saying that it depends on whether there's an obligation to tear  for that relative. If there's an obligation, then the one who tore is חייב, if not the one who tore is פטור.

However, one should definitely not do it Lechatchilah. (confirmed source: [here page 9](http://www.jewishpathways.com/files/Death_and_Burial.pdf))

Interesting aside: you specifically asked about death. But the same would also apply to tearing for the Kosel. Which is one of the ways to avoid having to tear for the Kosel (i.e. by having the first visit done on Shabbos or Friday Afternoon) [see [here](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/410,44810/Any-laws-I-should-know-before-seeing-the-Kotel-for-the-first-time.html) for source].

Two things I'm not sure of though, which I would hope someone could cover in the comments:

- If the death is on Friday afternoon or Rosh Chodesh, should kriyah be performed?
- If Kriyah should be performed later, if it wasn't performed because of one of the above cases

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask