# Tearing kriyah at the Kotel ha-Maaravi after visiting on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, mourning-aveilus, kotel-western-wall

Assume the following:

- We should tear kriyah at the Kotel ha-Maaravi (Western Wall) if we haven't been there in 30 days.
- We don't tear kriyah on shabbat.

Now, answer this question: If I go to the Kotel ha-Maaravi on Shabbat, am I exempt from tearing kriyah if I go back on Sunday?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9235/1059, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8229/1059, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8587/1059

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Rabbi Yechiel Michel Tukachinsky - [Ir Hakodesh V'Hamikdash 3](http://www.teachittome.com/seforim2/seforim/ir_hakodesh_vehamikdash_3.pdf):17:4 - if one sees the Kosel at a time when one does not do Kriyah as in your case, then one would not be required to do Kriyah if one sees it again within 30 days.

Comment: R Tukachinsky, actually, explicitly says in 3:17:3 that one never tears on seeing the Kosel. His comments in 3:17:4 are about seeing the place of the Azara on the Temple Mount.